# SQL combine 2 tables

Tags: sql

I am a beginner so sorry if this question sounds so simple. I need help in creating a nested SQL for this situation

For each record in table A contains multiple records in table B. 
For example, table A has a summary balance for January 2013. table B has the detailed In and out transactions for table A.

How do I get this result

```
DECLARE @DateStart DATETIME
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME
SET @DateStart = A.MonthYear
SET @DateEnd = EOMONTH(@DateStart)

Select A.MonthYear, A.StartBalance, A.EndBalance, Sum(B.InTransaction)
    WHERE B.TransactionDate BETWEEN @DateStart and @DateEnd 
          AND A.InventoryType = B.InventoryType
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT A.monthyear, 
       A.startbalance, 
       A.endbalance, 
       Sum(B.intransaction) 
FROM   table a 
       JOIN table b 
         ON b.col = a.col 
            AND B.transactiondate BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd 
GROUP  BY A.monthyear, 
          A.startbalance, 
          A.endbalance
```